# const String API_BASE_URL in Dart

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, configuration

First I have to say I'm new to the Flutter and related technologies. Resonantly I have started working with opensource Flutter project. I faced this problem during setup the project in my local environment. In the README section this step described as follows,

> Configure the `lib/config.dart` using the format provided in `lib/config_example.dart`.

So as they said I have created new file inside the lib directory called `config.dart` and added the code snippet from the mentioned example folder.

```
const String API_BASE_URL = "";
```

Now what the problem is I don't know what should I add to the `API_BASE_URL` I have refereed internet and slimier stack overflow questions but still unable to find an answer. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This variable is for url to your backend (rest api usually/firebase). If you dont have backend you dont need this variable.

Comment: @KirillMatrosov I do have firebase backend but how can I find this URL

Comment: read documentation for [firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/api/reference/rest)

Comment: @KirillMatrosov I do but itis huge unable to find my solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For implementing firebase in a flutter, you must require `google-services.json` file in the project. 
Check out [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=android) for the implementation of a firebase and [this](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7015592) for configuration in flutter for better understanding.

Comment: I have already downloaded google-services.json. Thanks for the answer plese can you specify where can I found my API_BASE_URL then I can accept the answer

Comment: simply while implementing network-based API in the application, there is a main base API URL through all data that comes to the app. firebase googleservice.json itself takes care of all this there is no need for API_BASE_URL required to set in the project. I guess You have gone through the improper reference, this below link will surely help to get a perfect idea of firebase implementation. https://medium.com/47billion/how-to-use-firebase-with-flutter-e4a47a7470ce